# .NetCore Authentication cookie not persistent across all request [Inermittent issue]

Tags: .net-core, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

We have an application which provides sso authentication. three other applications get authenticated from sso application. Once user get logged into all application, I initiated a sso logout. sso app send logout request to app1 and then app1 respond with SAML logout response.Once sso app received SAML logout response, it will send a logout request to app2 and then app3. Some times this whole flow works fine and sometime not.
I have seen that when app2/app3/app1 is responding, sso application authentication cookies got disappeared from browser and that request becomes unautneticated for sso app and user is not able to logout from all applications.

Authentication middleware:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
   .AddCookie(options =>
   {
       options.Cookie.Name = ".federation_user_authentication";
       options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.None;
       options.Cookie.Path = "/";
       options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
       options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(
                       Convert.ToDouble(
                           systemParamsCollection[nameof(JwtTokenVerificationParameterModel.ValidFor)]));
       options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.None;
       if (Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["IsCloudDeployment"]))
       {
           options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always; // Cookie/sso login will not work on localhost. because it is on http
       }
   });
```

Could you let me know what is reason and why authentication cookie got disappeared after 2-3 times redirection between apps ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is probably browser cookie security.

If the cookie security is configured with `SameSite=Strict` a browser will not send a cookie to the server on one domain if the call originates from another domain.

If the cookie security is `SameSite=Lax` GET and POST calls is treated differently. During GET calls the browser will let the cookies get through. But on POST calls the browser will not send a cookie to the server on one domain if the call originates from another domain.

More info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie

Comment: Could you please elaborate this line "The same goes for at POST call if the SameSite=Lax". and second thing is that our all cookies are set to secure  with samesite mode is none.